# Android File Storage Options - External + Internal

Tags: android, storage, external, internal

I am making an educational App and want my users to be able to choose which package they want and download only that package to the device.  So basically, my App has a "data" folder.  If a user picks a package say "Signals and Systems", my app should download it from a http server to a private location on the device from which my app can then present data to the user.  (the downloadable content is 20-30 MB so i want to download it to external storage if possible or else internal but either way should be private to the app)

Now, I went through the google docs and it seems that data can be saved in Internal memory or External memory.  What I don't understand is what do they mean by External memory?  **If I code my app for using external storage and  if the user chooses to install my app in internal memory, do I have to rewrite code to fetch data from internal memory?**

**EDIT 1**

I got answers to that but now I have a different question.  If I want to put some files in the APK, I import them into Android Studio Assets folder.  But, now I want to put some files outside the APK but package with the APK.  i.e. My file should be downloaded along with the APK to a private storage location.  How do I do that?  How do I setup Android Studio for that?

Comment: check updated answer for your question. Also, it is not a good idea to update your question with new questions. create a separate question if your question is significant. trivial queries can be asked in comments.

Comment: also got through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of asking question.

Answer (score 0):

Android have 3 major categories of memory:

1. System : used for OS
2. Internal : used for app installation and app private data
3. External : used to store files and or may be apps (this can be a SD card)

you can chose between Internal and External to store your app data.

Your app will get installed on internal memory by default and user can move it on external storage.

any of this will not affect your implementation for data storage, you need not to rewrite any code.

also have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

**Update:**

to answer your updated question you can keep any required file in assets and it will be bundled with your APK.

check [this document](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#ApplicationModules)

> **main/assets/**
>
> This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files.
> Files that you save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the
> original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the
> same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a
> stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good
> location for textures and game data.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.  I would go with third option.  But now, I want to place a dummy file in the External storage and want my app to read it for testing purposes.  How do i do this in android studio?

Comment: Search on Google there are lots of tutorials for reading, writing and creating files on external storage

Comment: I am asking if its possible to **manually** place the files through the Android Studio IDE so that when the app is installed in the testing device, it would load the file using getExternalFilesDir() and process.  There are many tutorials for reading and writing from external storage through code and I would use them in the app.  But right now, I only want to test by placing a dummy file.

Comment: Yes it's possible. from the ide you can access [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) from [device monitor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monitor.html) to explore and push pull files on your device. you can also explore external memory after connecting your device to any PC with USB cable.